# How to update user info with react redux?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am learning react-redux, I am creating a simple CRUD app using JSON placeholder, now I am able to display data and delete data using post and delete method's but I can't figure out how to update data with put method in redux, I need help.

**

> **Here is a live demo in the sandbox: [redux live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/throne1986/reduxa?file=/src/redux/acitons/users/Users.js)**

**

Here is what I have so far, user component (just part of codes)

```
return(
      <div>
            <table id="users">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {userData &&
                    userData.users &&
                    userData.users.map(user => 
                <tbody>
                  {user.editing ? <UserForm user={user} key={user.id} />:
                    <tr key={user.id}>

                        <td>{user.id}</td>
                        <td>{user.name}</td>
                        <td>
                        <button key={user.id} type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-link" onClick={() => deleteUser(user.id)}>
                            <i className="material-icons">delete</i>
                        </button>
                        <button key={user.id} type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-link" onClick={() =>editUser(user.id)}>
                            <i className="material-icons">edit</i>
                        </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  }
                </tbody>
                )}

            </table>
      </div>
  )
```

And here is userfom component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function UserForm() {
    const { edit, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                 <input name="name" defaultValue="test" ref={edit} />
                 <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserForm
```

And here is Edit user in reducer

```
 case ActionTypes.EDIT_USER:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    users:state.users.map((user)=>user.id === action.payload ? {
                        ...user,editing:!user.editing
                    }:user)

                }
```

Now when I click edit and submit the data, it refreshes the page and nothing is updated in user info ([check it here live](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/throne1986/reduxa?file=/src/redux/acitons/users/Users.js)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It looks like that the 'Submit' button uses a handleSubmit from react-hooks, but it should probably be your own handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code, update user can work now.

[revised version demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-browser-dhyv7?file=/src/components/Users.js)

1. redux/user/Users

```
// need to pass whole user data as parameter 
export const updateUser = data => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      // add data into axios second arg
      .put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${data.id}`, data)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(editUser(data.id));
        // refresh user list after successfully update
        dispatch(fetchUsers());
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorMsg = error.message;
        dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(errorMsg));
      });
  };
};
```

2. components/UserForm:

You don't need react-hook-form, just use the useDispatch hook that provided by react-redux.

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { editUser, updateUser } from "../redux/acitons/users/Users";

function UserForm({ user }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [name, setName] = React.useState(user.name);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(updateUser({ ...user, name }));
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    dispatch(editUser(user.id));
  };

  return (
    {/* I modify it to inline edit row  */}
    <tr>
      <td>{user.id}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          defaultValue={user.name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={handleCancel}>
          <i className="material-icons">Cancel</i>
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-success btn-link"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          <i className="material-icons">save</i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default UserForm;
```

But you will notice that new user list is still old after update successfully, this is normal 
https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder/issues/42#issuecomment-284507310

and I suggest you can group your actions/reducer/constants into one file by feature, this is useful when your app grow, You can easily find the file you want to modify when your code base becomes very large.

for example:

```
|-- reducers
|---- auth.js
|---- counter.js
|---- index.js
|---- store.js
|---- users.js
```

This approach actually has a name called [duck pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)

Comment: Hi can u chekc this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351371/how-to-insert-data-with-post-using-react-redux ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't have a lot of knowledge about react-hook-form but I'll try to help you, first you need to pass a function to your 'handleSubmit' because otherwise I think that you don't prevent the default behaviour of a submit, I mean the handleSubmit function doesn't do a 'event.preventDefault()', so you can put the following below your useForm hook:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Then in your jsx you will have

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

I'm not sure because as I told you I don't use react-hook-form, but I think another bug that I saw is that you are trying to get a 'edit' property from the useForm hook, well that won't work, you are not declaring a variable there, you are trying to access a property from the useForm hook, so in order of tracking the changes of your inputs you should use 'register', I mean you should have the following code:

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
```

And you should update your jsx with the following:

```
<input name="name" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
```

Now with every submit you will have your form with the changes in the console.log that we add in our onSubmit function. 
You already connected redux with your Users component, I mean you are using mapDispatchToProps and because of that inside your Users components you will be able to access the edit prop to dispatch an editUser action. So in order to continue your work with redux you can pass that prop via this.props.editUser to your UserForm component and continue. Another option is connect the UserForm component with redux and access the editUser prop.