# data is not reloading after being saved

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm storing data using API, it saves successfully, but it's not reloading in the datagrid. I have manually refresh the entire page to view the data. I tried to put the storing variable in a function, then call that function, but it's not rendering I guess. kindly help me. Thank you in advance

here's the code

```
const ContactDataGrid = ({ rows, columns }) => {
 const [platform, setPlatform] = useState([]);
 const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
 const [Rows, setRows] = useState([]);
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const [formInputData, setformInputData] = useState(
   {
     name: '',
     details: '',
   }
 );

 const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
 const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

 const handleChange = (evnt) => {
   setOpen(true)
   const newInput = (data) => ({
     ...data,
     [evnt.target.name]: evnt.target.value
   });
   setformInputData(newInput);
 }

 const showData = () => setRows(rows);

 useEffect(() => {
   setPlatform(rows);
   showData();
 }, [rows]);
 console.log()

 const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
   evnt.preventDefault();
   const formData = new FormData();    //formdata object
   formData.append('nickname', formInputData.nickname);   //append the values with key, value pair
   formData.append('target', formInputData.target);
   const config = {
     headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
   }
   axios.post('http://localhost:8006/api/v2/save/beneficiary', formData, config)
     .then(response => {
       if (response.data.success === true) {
         showData()
         alert(response.data.message)
       }
     })
     .catch(error => {
       alert(error.message);
     });
   setformInputData({ nickname: "", target: "" });
   setOpen(false);
 }

 function escapeRegExp(value) {
   return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
 }
 const requestSearch = (searchValue) => {
   const searchRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(searchValue), 'i');
   const filteredRows = platform.filter((row) => {
     return Object.keys(row).some((field) => {
       return searchRegex.test(row[field]?.toString() || '');
     });
   });
   setRows(filteredRows);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you request success the variable `rows` don't change so show data load the old data. You can trigger when post data you request fetch data again and change datagrid.

Comment: can you tell me how to trigger it?

Comment: You call function to fetch data again after you post successfully. You can use your fetch data function in another component by pass through props or use dispatch action in redux or or many other way you call are fetch data and change value of variable `row`.

Comment: example in this link when update user using redux, you can dispatch action fetch user to fetch all new users like code below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336700/20029843